# compare 2 multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

---

**Php: Compare 2 multidimentinal arrays in php
I have 02 arrays and i would like to compare it.**

```
    $first = array(
          0 => array(
                 "id" => 45,
                 "name" => "chicago"
               ),
          1 => array(
                 "id" => 78,
                 "name" => "LA"
               ),
    );

    $second = array(
          0 => array(
                 "id" => 45,
                 "name" => "chicago"
               ),
          1 => array(
                 "id" => 78,
                 "name" => "LA"
               ),
          2 => array(
                 "id" => 95,
                 "name" => "Washington"
               ),
    );
```

After compare the 2 arrays i would like to have this

```
    $cityMissing =array (
                  0 => array(
                     "id" => 95,
                     "name" => "Washington"
                   );


**Please, I need your help.**
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried first, so we may help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php):

```
$arrayFirst = array("0" => array("id", "45") );
$arraySecond = array("0" => array("id", "45"), "1" => array("id", "95"));

$result = array_diff_assoc($arraySecond, $arrayFirst);

print_r($result);

Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => id
        [1] => 95
    )
)
```

Comment: that would be a comment

Comment: it's don't work, i have an error: Notice: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function array_diff_assoc_recursive($a, $b){
        // Get all of the "compare against" arrays
        $b = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
        // Initial return value
        $ret = array();

        // Loop over the "to" array and compare with the others
        foreach($a as $key=>$val){
            // We should compare type first
            $aType = gettype($val);
            // If it's an array, we recurse, otherwise we just compare with "==="
            $args = $aType === 'array' ? array($val) : true;

            // Let's see what we have to compare to
            foreach($b as $x){
                // If the key doesn't exist or the type is different,
                // then it's different, and our work here is done
                if(!array_key_exists($key, $x) || $aType !== gettype($x[$key])){
                    $ret[$key] = $val;
                    continue 2;
                }

                // If we are working with arrays, then we recurse
                if($aType === 'array'){
                    $args[] = $x[$key];
                }
                // Otherwise we just compare
                else{
                    $args = $args && $val === $x[$key];
                }
            }

            // This is where we call ourselves with all of the arrays we got passed
            if($aType === 'array'){
                $comp = call_user_func_array(array(get_called_class(), 'array_diff_assoc_recursive'), $args);
                // An empty array means we are equal :-)
                if(count($comp) > 0){
                    $ret[$key] = $comp;
                }
            }
            // If the values don't match, then we found a difference
            elseif(!$args){
                $ret[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }
```